# How can I hide one div in Wordpress using jQuery, and show it when another div is hidden?

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

Somehow this doesn't work. The #autoverkocht should be hidden by default, unless the .b-car-info__price is hidden, #autoverkocht should be shown.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("#autoverkocht").css({   
    display: "none",
    visibility: "hidden"
});
})

if($('.b-car-info__price').is(":hidden")){


      $('#autoverkocht').css('visibility', 'visible');
}
```

It's either the jQuery above or the functions.php code below that doesn't work.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
    'your-script', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/autoverkocht.js', // this is the location of your script file
    array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
);
```

}

Comment: The `if()` needs to also be inside the `ready()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline styling like below:

```
<div id='autoverkocht' style='display: none;'>
</div>
```

or use css styling like this:

```
#autoverkocht{
  display: none;
}
```

And in the jquery do this:

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    if($('.b-car-info__price).is(":hidden")){
      $('#autoverkocht').show();        
    }
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Important to use `jQuery(document).ready(function($){` since wordpress uses `noConflict()`

Comment: Used validator to check the code, but it returns: Error: Line 2: Unexpected token ILLEGAL?

Comment: Which is the line 2 it is referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Think jQuery [toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and [hide](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) is what you need .

```
$('#autoverkocht').hide()
$('#autoverkocht, .b-car-info__price').on(
  'click',
 function() 
 {
   $('#autoverkocht, .b-car-info__price').toggle()
 }
);
```

Hope this is what you require   ......